# What parameters are passed to open a LookupPage?

Tags: lookup, documentation

Trying to untangle a legacy app, and I see this code:

```
url = '/_ui/common/data/LookupPage'
                + '?lkfm=Conf_Search'
                + '&lknm=Conf_LineSearch'
                + '&lktp=005'
                + '&lksrch=*';

pd.openLookup(url, 670, 1, '');
```

Found out the parameters passed to open a LookupPage are internal to SF and not addressed in the docs.

I found [this SE question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61406/what-values-for-the-lktp-parameter-are-supported-by-the-standard-salesforce-lo) that asks about range of values for one parameter, but I can't find info about any of the parameters.

Is there a good explanation of what the parameters do and how to use them?

Edit: [Got a response from the Salesforce Docs twitter account](https://twitter.com/salesforcedocs/status/552229713742004224) that those are internal Salesforce parameters and are not addressed in the docs. So makes sense why I can't find them.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Ron Hess's reply [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008llAIAQ).

- lknm  -- looks like a custom field id ( input element in the
  document.element... )
- lkfm=editPage  name of the form (
  document.editPage)
- lktp == type of the object to view in the lookup 
  list ( three char prefix)
- lksrch == search string to put into the
  lookup input box

Comment: Just to add that lktp can take some additional values like lead_queue (show only Queues that can be used as owners for Leads), lead_case (ditto for Case) and StandardUserLookup (lookup a user). Also, it would appear that not all 3 character prefixes are supported (for instance it doesn't work with 00G for Groups)